# Ignore_User_Abort(true) On Unload of HTML File Through Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I searched around for how to use the ignore_user_abort(true) feature to allow an Update Sql statement to execute, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is what I have:

From .html

```
<body onUnload="winClose()"></body>
```

From .js (ajax)

```
... var queryString = "?id=" + id;
xmlhttp.open("GET", "signoff.php" + queryString, true);
```

From signoff.php

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
... connect to DB
$id = $_GET['id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE Login_Table SET signed_in = '' WHERE login_id = '$id'");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I can verify that the ajax connection is working and the variables are passing by alerting the queryString, however the sql statement is not executing.  I tried a few variations of the ignore_user_abort, however with no luck.  Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I connect to the DB where I typed ... connect to DB.  I tested my connection string and it is fine.  Maybe a php page with ignore_user_abort cannot not be called through Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you would want to load this kind of page using jquery, use some redirects when all you want to do is simply log someone out.

**Stick to this:**

- Expire Sessions (if you want to make sure someone signs out, expire
  after 15 min no activity, etc;)
- Have a logout button simply that calls a PHP page that handles your logout DB update.

From what I see above you make the process overly complex and it ends up breaking or is unreliable. My assumption is that you just want to log someone out forcefully after page unload.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I actually wanted a value of 1 to become NULL when a user logs out.  The reason is so I can have the database execute specific statements based on who is logged in.  When someone logs in, the db Updates the user account with a 1.  When they navigate away form the page, the db is supposed to Update the account with a NULL value.

Comment: Please add the table definition to your question. You might do the wrong thing for the column type here.